# How to transfer a git repository with LFS file to another repository?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

We have a local git server, with LFS files. We are planning to move everything on MS Azure DevOps.
After some research, I read that it was advise to do a "mirror" clone, to have everything(tags at least):

> git clone --mirror

Then, since I've some LFS files, I wanted to get them too:

> git lfs fetch --all

But I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to call git rev-parse --git-dir --show-toplevel: "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree\n"
Not in a git repository.
```

For what I'm reading, git lfs fetch doesn't work on a `bare` repository(not that I know what this is, but I think it's related to the `--mirror` option.

So my question is: What should I do to transfer everything to this new repository? (the local server will be shutdown after this).

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What should I do to transfer everything to this new repository? (the local server will be shutdown after this).

That because the incompatibility between `git-lfs` and the default directory name that git uses for `bare` repos.

To resolve this issue, you could try to use following git commands:

```
git clone --bare https://xxx/xxx/old-repository.git
cd old-repository.git
git lfs fetch --all
git push --mirror https://xxx/xxx/new-repository.git
git lfs push --all https://xxx/xxx/new-repository.git
```

You could check this document [Mirroring a repository that contains Git Large File Storage objects](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.8/user/articles/duplicating-a-repository/#mirroring-a-repository-that-contains-git-large-file-storage-objects) for some details.